# Como passar o texto salvo para uma variável em js?

Tags: javascript

eu sei que pra copiar basta usar:

```
document.execCommand("copy");
```

eu pensei que:

```
document.execCommand("paste");
```

mostrava como resultado o que foi copiado, mas isto não está acontecendo.

Alguém sabe como jogar pra uma variável o conteúdo copiado?

Comment: As respostas resolveram, ajudaram? Tem algum problema que possa ser melhorado? Se atendeu ao problema, marque ️✔️ na resposta para que a pergunta não fique pendente de resolução. ObG!

Answer (score 1):

O comando `document.execCommand` tem pouca ou nenhuma compatibilidade entre os navegadores (**[veja documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)**). E mesmo que fosse totalmente funcional, o comando `"paste"` não serve para esse caso. O comando `"copy"` manda o texto selecionado para a área de transferência e não passa por variáveis.

O que você pode fazer é usar uma função com `window.getSelection` que captura o texto selecionado, e em seguida você pode atribuir a uma variável qualquer.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function selTexto() {
   var texto = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection().toString() : null;
   return texto;
}

document.onkeyup = function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 16){ // tecla SHIFT
      var copiado = selTexto();
      console.clear();
      console.log("O valor da variável 'copiado' agora é:", copiado);
   }
}
```

```html
<strong>Selecione parte do texto abaixo e tecle SHIFT:</strong>
<br><br>
Olá mundo!
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.oncopy = function(e) {
    var variavel = (window.getSelection().toString());
    
    console.log(variavel);
}
```

```html
Ao selecionar uma parte desse texto **e copiar** com o menu de contexto ou 
pressionar CONTROL+C,
você vai copiar o que estiver selecionado para a área de transferência e
jogado para uma variável.
```

> O método getSelection() retorna a string do texto selecionado pelo usuário.

Veja como funciona:

```js
function showSelection() {
    document.getElementById('selectedText').value = document.getSelection();

    var variavel=document.getElementById('selectedText').value;
    console.log(variavel);  
}

document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP)

document.onmouseup = showSelection
```

```html
<P>
O Congresso não deverá legislar sobre o estabelecimento de uma religião ou proibir o
livre exercício do mesmo; ou abreviando a liberdade de expressão ou de imprensa; ou o direito de
  o povo se reunir pacificamente e pedir ao governo uma solução dos problemas.
</P>
<textarea id="selectedText" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
```